# Make a django query with a list of parameter

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

i have a list of id like :

```
ids = [1,2,3]
```

Is there a quicker way to do a query for all of them than a for ?
Like:

```
users = []
for id in ids :
    users.append(User.objects.get(id=id))
```

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use the [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) filter function:

```
users = User.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
```